# ASP.Net Async MVC controller function causes Razor View Engine error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-mac

I am having issues with an asynchronous ASP.Net MVC controller method. I have a controller with one view that returns on a HttpGet to '/home' route. It works fine synchronously, but i wanted to test some of my database functionality so i changed it to asynchronous and added some code to write a model to my database.

```
[RoutePrefix("home")]
public class HomeController : AsyncController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> IndexAsync()
    {
        // DEBUGGING - TEST WRITING USER TO DB
        var user = new UserModel(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "test", "test", "test@test.com", "tester");
        await user.WriteToDatabase();
        // DEBUG END

        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

If I remove the lines between the comments the view is returned just fine, however, if I don't remove the lines between the comments, I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException
>
> The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations. The following locations were
>   searched:
>
> ~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
>
> ~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
>
> ~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
>
> ~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
>
> ~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
>
> ~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml
>
> ~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
>
> ~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
>
> Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
>
> Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or
>   object): System.Web.Mvc.

I have verified that the view exists in the path "~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml" and because the page is loaded just fine in the synchronous version I know that the view's syntax is correct. The database write operation is successful but the view just cant be found for some reason.

I just don't know why turning the method asynchronous would suddenly result in a razor view engine error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Although performing async actions you should leave the name of the action as `Index` and not `IndexAsync`. that way you could also juet do `return View();` as apposed to what you are currently doing. The so-called nameing convention for async does not apply to action names. It causes the same problem you are encountering.

Comment: You should also not use `AsynController` and just have your controller inherit from plain `Controller` which can handler async actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [AsyncController Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.asynccontroller(v=vs.118).aspx) Provided for backward compatibility with ASP.NET MVC 3

Although performing async actions you should leave the name of the action as `Index` and not `IndexAsync`. that way you could also juet do `return View();` as apposed to what you are currently doing. The so-called nameing convention for async does not apply to action names.

You should also not use `AsynController` and just have your controller inherit from plain `Controller` which can handler async actions.

> [Remarks:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.asynccontroller(v=vs.118).aspx#Anchor_6) The Controller class in ASP.NET MVC 4 and higher supports the asynchronous patterns.

```
[RoutePrefix("home")]
public class HomeController : Controller {
    //Matches GET home
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index() {
        // DEBUGGING - TEST WRITING USER TO DB
        var user = new UserModel(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "test", "test", "test@test.com", "tester");
        await user.WriteToDatabase();
        // DEBUG END

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I implemented the changes you suggested but I am still seeing the same error, unfortunately. I have verified that the index exists in the correct place in my directory structure so I know it's there I just have no idea why it can't seem to find the Index.cshtml file.

Comment: I ended up resolving the issue, I'm not sure what the actual problem is still though. I was working on a macbook pro using Visual Studio for Mac when I ran into the issue, so i changed over to a windows machine and I no longer have the same problem, it works as expected. It seems to only be an issue when developing on a macOS system.

Comment: i use attribute routing so its small but here it is:

    
    `public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        }
    }`

Comment: @JakeLeveroni yes that config is correct. I was on my mobile so did not see your comments till now.

Comment: @JakeLeveroni Just for troubleshooting. Try upgrading to MVC5 and see if you get the same problem with the different platforms.

Comment: @JakeLeveroni I'm a bit late to the party, but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848492/how-to-use-async-in-asp-net-mvc-for-mono) - Mono doesn't seem to support async/await with MVC yet. I found this because I'm also having the same problem on a Macbook Pro, but unfortunately no indication of when it will be implemented..

Comment: Like @JakeLeveroni me too. I'm changing platform from Mac to WIn and works perfectly!! Visual Studio for Mac is not still mature!!! :(