# How to use async in ASP.Net MVC for Mono

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, mono, visual-studio-2017

I am creating an ASP.Net MVC project in Mono using Visual Studio 2017 for Mac. I added the basic controllers, view, models, etc and it's working fine. However, as soon as make the Index method async I am getting the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
```

This is the code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
   ...
}
```

Searching for some information I found that seems the Mono project doesn't support the async pipeline ([mono The view 'Index' or its master was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629192/mono-the-view-index-or-its-master-was-not-found))

And in the Mono project website (https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/) it describe the different compatibility characteristics by version.

Does anyone know any workaround to use async in Mono? Or when it will be supported?

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest using .net core